# Why is $E(XY)=E(YE(X \mid Y))$?

Tags: probability

From what I could find online, the proof of the above statement is:

$$E(XY)=E(E(XY \mid Y))=E(YE(X \mid Y)).$$

I understand the first step of the proof. What I do not get is the second step: how did $E(XY \mid Y)$ become $YE(X \mid Y)$?

Answer (score 0):

When you operate given $Y$, the value of $Y$ is a constant, and so it can be factored outside of the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of conditional expectation from Davar Khoshnevisan's book [*Probability*](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-80) (which is equivalent to the usual definitions) $E(X|Y)$ is the random variably with $E(X|Y) \in \sigma(Y)$ and satisfying $E(\xi X) = E(\xi E(X|Y))$ for all bounded random variables $\xi \in \sigma(Y)$. This random variable is a.s. unique, so another random variable satisfying this properties must be a.s. equal.

Assume $X$, $Y$ are non-negative. Choose any bounded $\xi \in \sigma(Y)$. I want to show that $$E(\xi E(XY | Y)) = E(\xi XY) = E(\xi Y E(X|Y))$$ The first part of the relation is certainly true by the definition of conditional expectation, so what remains to be shown is $E(\xi XY) = E(\xi Y E(X|Y))$.

If $Y$ is bounded then $\xi Y = \zeta$ is bounded too and

$$E(\xi Y E(X | Y)) = E(\zeta E(X | Y)) = E(\zeta X) = E(\xi X Y)$$

and we are done. Suppose now that $Y$ is not bounded. Then use $Y_n := \min(Y, n)$; each of these random variables are bounded so

$$E(\xi Y_n E(X | Y)) = E(\zeta_n E(X | Y)) = E(\zeta_n X) = E(\xi X Y_n)$$

By the monotone convergence theorem we can say that $\lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n = Y$ and

$$E(\xi Y E(X|Y)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} E(\xi Y_n E(X | Y)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} E(\xi X Y_n) = E(\xi X Y)$$

If we do not have $X$ and $Y$ non-negative, then we say $X = X_+ - X_-$ and $Y = Y_+ - Y_-$ and use the linearity of both expectations and conditional expectations.

---

The above proof is very general; we can replace $E(X|Y)$ with $E(X|\mathscr{F})$ and require $Y \in \mathscr{F}$ and the proof would still hold. If we assume that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous or discrete random variables then we can make things simpler.

For the continuous case, write
\begin{align}
E(\xi E(XY | Y)) &= \int_\mathbb{R} \xi(y) E(XY|Y = y) f(y) dy \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \xi(y) E(Xy|Y = y) f(y) dy \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \xi(y) y E(X|Y = y) f(y) dy \\
&= E(\xi Y E(X|Y))
\end{align}

The same can be done for the discrete case in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not very familiar with this definition of conditional expectation though; my understanding is more intuitive than rigorous. Is there another way to intuitively understand this fact, or is this something that can only be proved rigorously?

Comment: The intuitive understanding is that if you know Y then Y is a constant and can be factored out of the expectation, just as the other answer said. I'm glad I could help. If you're satisfied, please click to accept the answer.